# Promises Chaining in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In promises chaining in angularjs, we should wait for the result of the previous request before making another request.  Then how we called it as asynchronous calls?

Comment: Your question is a little vague, can you elaborate and give an example of what your are trying to do, what have you tried so far, etc?

Comment: No, you shouldn't (and can't) wait. You're just registering callbacks that are called when the response is available.

Comment: Being asynchronous means the current flow will complete synchronously and the callback code will be executed only after completing the current API/call. Aysnc means some part of code can be run after completing an API call. I hope it helps in understanding the concept.

Answer (score 0):

In my project, i want to create new deliverynote then its details after entering the product details to deliverynote, remove products from stock. Atlast display the deliverynotes list. Its a chain process. I used angularjs for frontend and nodejs for backend.

Here is my code below:

```
 //save delivery data 
$scope.savedeliverynote = function(){
    $scope.submitted         = true;
    $scope.addNoteform       = false;
    $scope.showquotationlist = false;
    $scope.showstockdetails  = false;
    if ($scope.formData.length != 0 && $scope.selectedRows.length != 0 && $scope.stockDetails.length != 0) {
        var noteData = {
            'deliverynotes'        : $scope.formData,
            'deliverynotesdetails' : $scope.selectedRows,
            'deliverynoteserials'  : $scope.stockDetails,
            'totalamount'          : $scope.grandtot,
            'statusid'             : "5c57c67fafa1eafcb6281d4a",
        };
        savealldeliverydatas(noteData);
    }
}
async function savealldeliverydatas(noteData){
    try{

        const promise1 = await_delivery_notes(noteData);
        const promise2 = await_delivery_details();
        const promise3 = $scope.deliverynotes_full();

    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}
function await_delivery_notes(noteData){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        DeliverynotesService.saveDeliveryNote(noteData).then(function(response){
            console.log(response);

        });
        resolve() 
    });    
}  
function await_delivery_details(){
    var stockData = {
        'stock'   : $scope.stock,
        'serials' : $scope.stockDetails,
    };
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            StockService.changeStockQty(stockData).then(function(response){
                console.log(response);
            });
            resolve() 

    });    
}
```